# Mysql Query SELECT auto_increment given null

Tags: mysql

query create table :

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_master_status` (
 `tbms_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `tbms_desc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tbms_id_parent` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`tbms_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

after that I added some data to the table ..
but when I run this query, it returns `NULL` value :

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = "tb_master_status"
```

Why did it happen ?

Comment: Can you see other columns from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`? Perhaps it's a permissions issue of some kind.

Comment: *when I run this query, it returns NULL value* Zero rows or one row with NULL value?

Comment: I would always include a table_schema test just in case I lost track of where I am. Also if a row is returned and the auto_increment column is null then the table does not have auto_increment set..

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have checked, there auto_increment is set to null

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you didn't answer my question, you just copied your question again :-?

Answer (score 1):

you can try the permission for the user and following method

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "yourDatabaseName"
AND TABLE_NAME = "yourTableName"
```